# Select last children of tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I was working on a project but I could not find a way to select last children of dashboard

```
<div class="dashboard">
<div class="grid_6 alpha">
<div class="grid_6 omega">
<div class="grid_6 alpha">
<div class="grid_6 omega">
<div class="grid_6 alpha">
<div class="grid_6 omega"> //i wanna select this
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

i tried

```
.dashboard:last-child
.omega:last-child
```

Comment: Look at this SO search result : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+last+element  and your answer is here : stackoverflow.com/questions/10415016/is-it-possible-to-target-the-very-last-list-element-in-css/10415207#10415066   and  google : https://www.google.ca/#gs_rn=21&gs_ri=psy-ab&cp=19&gs_id=cn&xhr=t&q=css+selector+last+element

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-last-child

Comment: Please, consider to avoid using empty markup for styling purpose.

Comment: Using an empty div as your clearfix is archaic and unnecessary.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last child is `.clear`, not `.omega`, so `.omega:last-child` won't work.

If that `.clear` will always be there, use `.omega:nth-last-child(2)` instead.

If you cannot guarantee that, then it's not going to be feasible without some scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the nth-child() selector.
Link: [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

EDIT:Can't spell.

Comment: It's spelled nth-child, not n-thChild.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<span>John,</span>
<span>Karl,</span>
<span>Brandon,</span>
<span>Sam</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>Glen,</span>
<span>Tane,</span>
<span>Ralph,</span>
<span>David</span>
</div>

<script>
$("div span:last-child")
.css({color:"red", fontSize:"80%"})
.hover(function () {
      $(this).addClass("solast");
    }, function () {
      $(this).removeClass("solast");
    });
</script>
```